# Add red cross to remove the box from row

Tags: php

As you all seen a row and colum has box and x when you click x then that row gets removed.

How do I add this

[image]

[image]

I read in other thread

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('close').onclick = function(){
        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
        .removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
        return false;
    };
};
Css for close button

#close {
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:2px 5px;
    background:#ccc;
}

You may add a hover effect like

#close:hover {
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:2px 5px;
    background:#ccc;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Here is my PHP code

```
<?php 


    $post = get_post(get_the_ID());
    $auth = $post->post_author;

    $lnk = $privurl_m . 'priv_act=send&pid='.get_the_ID().'&uid='.$auth;

    $author = get_the_author();
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<span>'.sprintf(__('<a href="%s">%s</a> requested gig',"PricerrTheme"),$lnk,"<font color=\'red'>" . $author ."</font>").':</span><br/>';
    echo "Title: ".get_the_title(); echo'<br/> <span>';
    _e("Posted in","PricerrTheme");?> <?php echo get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'request_cat', '', ', ', '' );
    echo '</span>';
    echo '<input class="btnnn-class" type="btnnn-class" onClick="window.location.href=\'' . $lnk . '\'" value="Contact Buyer">' ;
    echo '</li>';


 ?>
```

How do I add the code to this so it adds x on each column and I can then press it and se if it goes away.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have duplicate `id`s. So you need to first change your CSS.

```
.close {
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:2px 5px;
    background:#ccc;
}

.close:hover {
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:2px 5px;
    background:#ccc;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Then in the PHP code, inside the loop, add the close button:

```
echo '<input class="btnnn-class" type="btnnn-class" onClick="window.location.href=\'' . $lnk . '\'" value="Contact Buyer"> <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>' ;
```

Comment: its added the cros when i click it , it dont remove it  how ever this code i found works <span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;'>x</span>   but it removed all the boxes

Comment: please help your code its not removing it ? what do i need to do